# nuget install does not actually install the software?

Tags: nuget

I created one internal nuget repository and stored 7zip nuget package in it.
Added internal repo using , `nuget sources Add -Name "localnuget" -Source http://10.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/repository/nuget-hosted/`

But when i used `nuget install 7Zip.sfx -Source localnuget` it is just extracting it and putting it inside a folder in which i can see tools folder which contains the 7Zip exe file.

nuget cli will install this exe file or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet.exe will not install software contained in NuGet packages. It will extract the contents of the NuGet package to a local folder.

tIf you are looking to install 7zip you should use one of the following:

1. The official 7zip installer.
2. [Chocolately](https://chocolatey.org) - if you want a command line package manager.